# Django Calculated Field Does Not Appear in Migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using the example from Django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/) and trying to create a calculated field in a Django Model. However, the fields don't show up in the migrations and then of course do not show up in the database.

Here's my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()

    def baby_boomer_status(self):
        "Returns the person's baby-boomer status."
        import datetime
        if self.birth_date < datetime.date(1945, 8, 1):
            return "Pre-boomer"
        elif self.birth_date < datetime.date(1965, 1, 1):
            return "Baby boomer"
        else:
            return "Post-boomer"

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        "Returns the person's full name."
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

And the migrations file:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Person',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('birth_date', models.DateField()),
        ],
    ),
```

Am I misinterpreting the property attribute? If so, how would one get a calculated field to appear in the database?

Comment: Yes, it is not an attribute at the database level. Only the model knows about it, and calcuates it *when needed*. But it is not *materialized*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well those "*calculated fields*" are *not* stored nor calculated at the database level. In fact the Database does not know anything about Python classes (or Django models) at all.

Those `@property`s are actually methods defined at the class level. It means that if somebody queries for `some_person.full_name`, Python will perform the calculations in the method, and return the result. In case one of the the attributes that is necessary changes (an "ingredient" so to speak), the result of this attribute can change as well (when you fetch it again).

Another implication is that you can *not* `.filter(..)` on such property. The database does *not* knows what `full_name` means, and hence you can for example *not* specify `Person.objects.filter(full_name__icontains='Bob')`, since the field and its corresponding value are not stored in the database.

Since the database has nothing to do with properties (or non-column attributes or methods), those are not included in the migration.

In case you need those at the database level (for example to filter on it), you can however perform a `.annotate(..)` in your queryset. But then you will have to encode the corresponding logic into a database expression. This can be hard, cumbersome, or even *impossible* (if for example the property performs operations on the file system, or queries a web service, since most databases do not support such operations).